# How to check if device has sensor for authentication with biometrics? (react-native-fingerprint-scanner)

Tags: react-native, fingerprint, biometrics, touch-id, face-id

I am using this library to authenticate with biometrics sensor such as face ID or fingerprint scanner but I would like to know how to detect whether the device has a sensor or not : `react-native-fingerprint-scanner`

according to it's documentation there is an API called `.isSensorAvailable()` but I dont understand what does it return in case there isn't any available sensor in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.isSensorAvailable()` API like this example below.

```
import FingerprintScanner from 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner'

    FingerprintScanner
                .isSensorAvailable()
                .then(() => {
                // Call the Fingerprint Scanner Method
                    FingerprintScanner
                        .authenticate({ description: 'Authenticate to access this' })
                        .then(() => {
                            // Method for Authentication
                            onAuthenticate()
                        })
                        // Call error method
                        .catch(error => onAuthenticationFailure(error))

                })
                 //Call the error method
                .catch(error => onAuthenticationFailure(error))
```

Comment: That's Great @dfgd

Answer (score 0):

import ReactNativeBiometrics from 'react-native-biometrics';

```
ReactNativeBiometrics.isSensorAvailable().then(resultObject => {
  const {available, biometryType} = resultObject;

  if (available && biometryType === ReactNativeBiometrics.TouchID) {
    console.log('TouchID is supported');

  } else if (available && biometryType === ReactNativeBiometrics.FaceID) {
    console.log('FaceID is supported');

  } else if (
    available &&
    biometryType === ReactNativeBiometrics.Biometrics
  ) {
    console.log('Biometrics is supported');
    try{
ReactNativeBiometrics.simplePrompt({
  promptMessage: 'Confirm fingerprint',
})
  .then(resultObject => {
    const {success} = resultObject;

    if (success) {
      console.log('successful biometrics provided');

    } else {
      console.log('user cancelled biometric prompt');
    }
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('biometrics failed');
  });
}
catch(e){
  console.log("Device not Support Fingerprint")
}
  } else {
    console.log('Biometrics not supported');
  }
});
```